# Keras custom layer compiles but shape error during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a custom layer (an attention layer) in Keras. The layer looks like this:

```
class MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention(Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_heads, alignment_vector_size, window_size = None, return_sequence=False, mode="add", **kwargs):
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.alignment_vector_size = alignment_vector_size
        self.return_sequence = return_sequence
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.mode = mode
        super(MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.input_shape_ = input_shape

        self.alignment_vector = self.add_weight(name="alignment_vector", shape=(self.n_heads, self.alignment_vector_size,), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name="kernel", shape=(self.alignment_vector_size, input_shape[2]), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(name="bias", shape=(self.alignment_vector_size,), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
        self.attention_weights = self.add_weight(name="attention_weights", shape=(self.n_heads, input_shape[1]), initializer='uniform', trainable=False)

        super(MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, hidden_state_sequence): 
        hidden_state_sequence.set_shape(self.input_shape_)

        if self.window_size is not None and self.input_shape_[1] > self.window_size:
            hidden_state_sequence = hidden_state_sequence[:, -self.window_size:]

        u = K.tanh( K.squeeze(K.dot(hidden_state_sequence, K.expand_dims(self.kernel)), axis=-1) + self.bias )

        score = K.squeeze(K.dot(u, K.expand_dims(self.alignment_vector)), axis=-1)
        self.attention_weights = K.softmax( score, axis=1 )
        self.attention_weights = K.permute_dimensions(self.attention_weights, (0,2,1))


        if self.return_sequence:
            print(K.expand_dims(self.attention_weights,axis=3).shape)
            print(hidden_state_sequence.shape)
            context_vector = K.expand_dims(self.attention_weights, axis=3)* hidden_state_sequence
            print(context_vector.shape)
            context_vector = K.permute_dimensions(context_vector, (0,2,1,3))
            context_vector = K.reshape(context_vector, (-1, context_vector.shape[1], context_vector.shape[2]*context_vector.shape[3]))
        else:
            context_vector = K.batch_dot(self.attention_weights, hidden_state_sequence)
            context_vector = K.reshape(context_vector, (-1, context_vector.shape[1]*context_vector.shape[2]))

        return context_vector

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.return_sequence:
            if self.window_size is not None and self.input_shape_[1] > self.window_size:
                return (input_shape[0], self.window_size, input_shape[2])


            return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2]*self.n_heads)
        else:
            return (input_shape[0], input_shape[2]*self.n_heads)
```

K.expand_dims(self.attention_weights, axis=3) has shape (?, 8, 80, 1) which is (batch_size, n_heads, sequence_length)

hidden_state_sequenc has shape (?, 80, 256) which is (batch_size, n_rnn_neurons)

and the context_vector before reshaping has shape (?, 8, 80, 256) and after reshaping (?, 80, 2048)

Used like this (with the imdb dataset):

```
inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
x = Embedding(max_features, 128)(inputs)

x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention(8, 10, return_sequence=True, name="Attention")(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)


predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)


model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
```

Everything compiles fine, but when I want to train the model, I get an shape error:

```
Epoch 1/6

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,8,80,1] vs. [32,80,256]
     [[Node: Attention_85/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_14/RMSprop/gradients/AddN_23"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Attention_85/ExpandDims_3, bidirectional_112/concat)]]
     [[Node: metrics_28/acc/Mean_1/_1241 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7813_metrics_28/acc/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-96d01a665879> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=6, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1703                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1704                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1705                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1706 
   1707     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1234                         ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
   1235 
-> 1236                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1237                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1238                         outs = [outs]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2480         session = get_session()
   2481         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2482                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2483         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2484 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,8,80,1] vs. [32,80,256]
     [[Node: Attention_85/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_14/RMSprop/gradients/AddN_23"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Attention_85/ExpandDims_3, bidirectional_112/concat)]]
     [[Node: metrics_28/acc/Mean_1/_1241 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7813_metrics_28/acc/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Attention_85/mul', defined at:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-267-95c219d983f6>", line 6, in <module>
    x = MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention(8, 10, return_sequence=True, name="Attention")(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-264-34a6413646ed>", line 91, in call
    context_vector = K.expand_dims(self.attention_weights, axis=3)* hidden_state_sequence
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 979, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1211, in _mul_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 5066, in mul
    "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [32,8,80,1] vs. [32,80,256]
     [[Node: Attention_85/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_14/RMSprop/gradients/AddN_23"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Attention_85/ExpandDims_3, bidirectional_112/concat)]]
     [[Node: metrics_28/acc/Mean_1/_1241 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7813_metrics_28/acc/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

It seems like there is an error during the multiplication, I dont know why though, since Keras seems to be fine with the shapes during call.

Comment: Please add the rest of the class definition of `MultiHeadAdditiveSelfAttention`; especially the `compute_output_shape` and the `build` function.

Comment: Sadly, this is not a minimal example to reproduce the error. Please add an example which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The code you (supposedly) use to create your model works and does not raise the exception mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code, now it reproduces the error